# how does rails route to a page when there is no action in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby On Rails. I watch many tutorials to make it clear how rails routes work. I am still unable to understand that if rails matches the URL with `GET` command in routes and then goes to the controller to see the action then how does it open `home/index` where home is my controller when my controller has no action at all.

**My HomeController**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout false 
end
```

My routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  get 'home/index'
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [2.1 Rendering by Default: Convention Over Configuration in Action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

> "By default, controllers in Rails automatically render views with names that correspond to valid routes."

So, it turns out your controller doesn't need to have the action in order to render the view.